# How to center a navigation bar?

Tags: html

```
<div class="topnav" align="middle">
  <a href="http://actividad.csjpr.xyz>Actividad</a>
  <a href="http://clase.csjpr.xyz">Clase</a>
  <a href="http://club.csjpr.xyz">Club</a>
  <a href="http://comite.csjpr.xyz">Comite</a>
  <a href="htt://competencia.csjpr.xyz">Competencia</a>
  <a href="http://deporte.csjpr.xyz">Deporte</a>
  <a href="http://oficina.csjpr.xyz">Oficina</a>
  <a href="http://organizacion.csjpr.xyz">Organización</a>
  <a href="http://programa.csjpr.xyz">Programa</a>
```

**This is what I currently have. I'd like to center it because it's automatically appearing on the left. Thank you.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to horizontally center a <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put " in line 2, this is the final code:

```
<div class="topnav" align="middle">
  <a href="http://actividad.csjpr.xyz">Actividad</a>
  <a href="http://clase.csjpr.xyz">Clase</a>
  <a href="http://club.csjpr.xyz">Club</a>
  <a href="http://comite.csjpr.xyz">Comite</a>
  <a href="htt://competencia.csjpr.xyz">Competencia</a>
  <a href="http://deporte.csjpr.xyz">Deporte</a>
  <a href="http://oficina.csjpr.xyz">Oficina</a>
  <a href="http://organizacion.csjpr.xyz">Organización</a>
  <a href="http://programa.csjpr.xyz">Programa</a>
</div>
```